# How to find multiple character and replace multiple characters using python3?

Tags: python, string

How to find multiple characters and replace mulitple characters using python3 ?

```
string = "us/i5/v"
l=[]
for i in string:
   if i == "u" :
       i = i.replace("u","w")
       l.append(i)
   if i == "s" :
      i = i.replace("s","5")
      l.append(i)
  if i == "i" :
      i = i.replace("i","1")
      l.append(i)
print(l)
```

> Expected Output:

```
w5/15/v
```

Comment: `string = string.replace("u","w").replace("s","5").replace("i","1")` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [translation table](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans):

```
translation_table = str.maketrans({'u': 'w', 's': '5', 'i':'1'})
string = "us/i5/v"
print(string.translate(translation_table))
# w5/15/v
```

Note that repetively using `replace` like `string.replace("u","w").replace("s","5")...` can lead to unwanted results, if one of the replacements gets replaced later. For example, if you want to replace `a` by `b` and `b` by `c`,

```
'ab'.replace('a', 'b').replace('b', 'c') # Don't !
```

would give `'cc'`, not `'bc'`.

So, unless you're sure you won't get into such problems, using `str.translate` is a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a lot of mappings, use a dict.

```
string = "us/i5/v"
d = {
    "u": "w",
    "s": "5",
    "i": "1"
}
new_string = "".join([d.get(e, e) for e in string])
```

Answer (score 0):

`replace()` is applied on strings and not chars, it can also be applied in sequence as below. You can also have the output as a list by using `list()`:

```
string = "us/i5/v"

string = string.replace("u","w").replace("s","5").replace("i","1")
l      = list(string)
print(string)
print(l)
```

Comment: Hi, while this may be an answer to OP's problem, code only answers are discouraged on StackOverflow. Please consider adding some explanation to the code provided as it will benefit both OP and future visitors. Thanks!

Comment: True, I will edit it in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

As is given in the comments the `.replace(before, after)` function handles strings, not just individual characters. You can chain them together as well. Building on your example

```py
transform_pairs = [
    ('u', w'),
    ('s', '5'),
    ('i', '1'),
    # more rules as you need
]
string = 'us/i5/v'
for old, new in transform_pairs:
    string = string.replace(old, new)
string == 'w5/15/v'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using tuple unpacking:

```
s = "us/i5/v"

# list of all the chars to replace along with their replacement
replaceList =  [("u", "w"), ("s", "5"), ("i", "1")]  

for elem in replaceList:
    s = s.replace(*elem)
print(s)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
w5/15/v
```